# Why is the font optional?

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I have created a struct to have my fonts pre cached available globally:

```
struct Fonts {
    static let avenirRegular = UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-Regular", size: 14.0)
}
```

Usage...:

```
xy.font = Fonts.avenirRegular
```

It tells me, that my constant is an Optional.

> Value of optional type 'UIFont?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Why is it an optional? Is there a chance that `AvenirNextCondensed-Regular` is not available on every iOS devices? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: The name is an arbitrary string, so `UIFont(name: "!§%&()wot???", size: 399)` must have a chance to return `nil`.

Comment: If you know, even in Objective-C the init method of the UIFont can return null if you send an arbitrary string for font name. In objective-c though the initializer is nullable initializer which means there also either you get an UIFont or you'll have null returned. To represent these nullable initializer (nilable in swift) we use optional return types which say the method can return an object of certain type or it'll return nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initializer you are using for `UIFont` is return optional `UIFont?` object ie the reason you are getting that suggestion for wrapping optional.

```
init?(name fontName: String, size fontSize: CGFloat)
```

Check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifont) of `UIFont` for more details.

Answer (score 5):

the "optional" here means that the problem is the font might not exist(even though we know it does) and you have to recognize it, by making it optional you are telling the compiler that I know the font is not part of your library BUT I am sure it is there.

Comment: If font with that name exists it will still return `UIFont?` because initializer OP is using return Optional `UIFont` object.

Comment: @NiravD absolutely :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer mate. Even tho your answer has the most upvotes (I have waited to see which will), I have chosen to check another answer. You explanation is good, but it might not be the "best" or the most "correct" one. You said, the font is not optional. But I'm receiving, as @NiravD mentioned, a `UIFont?`, so the returned value is indeed optional.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat

Answer (score 0):

Just use force unwrap to prevent this:

```
struct Fonts {
    static let avenirRegular = UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-Regular", size: 14.0)!
}
```

Comment: thank you for your thought. but that does not answer the question. I knew what i'm getting and how to solve it. the question was, WHY i am getting it. but it may be helpful for further spectators